# Прошу помощи с js match regexp

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст, содержащий вхождения вида `TEXT1/text2-text3`.

- TEXT1 — это одно из двух, TEXT11 или TEXT12 например.
- Далее всегда идет слеш (`/`).
- Далее следуют произвольные text2 и text3, разделенные тире (`-`).
- Заканчивается это табом или пробелом.

Мне нужно из этого текста вынести в массив все строки, попадающие под шаблон.
Пробовал много чего, в оконцовке

```
console.log(text.match(/(TEXT11\/.*[ \t])$/g));
```

Не могу объять я эти регулярки, помогите с разъяснениями плз.

UPD: вот пример: https://jsbin.com/cosukilivi/edit?html,js,output
Проблема - второй элемент массива - вся строка, а нужно из нее "выдернуть" два элемента SIP/text2-text3 разными элементами.

UPD2: Ответ из комментов: text.match(/\w+/\S+-\S+/g) работает, спасибо!

Comment: ну приведите пример текста то вашего.

Comment: так что ли? https://regex101.com/r/yrqB8T/3

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/t3dgx7/1

Comment: Привел в посте: https://jsbin.com/cosukilivi/edit?html,js,output

    второй элемент массива - вся строка, а нужно из нее "выдернуть" два элемента SIP/text2-text3 разными элементами

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/t3dgx7/2

Comment: СПАСИБО!!
text.match(/\w+\/\S+\-\S+/g) - работает! Магия блин.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text = `TEXT1/text2-text3 
TEXT2/sddasfkla dsajkh aksdjh f-ds asd asd a  
dhasjkhdk askdjh ajks
TEXT1/text2-text3 
TEXT2/sddasfkla dsajkh aksdjh fds asd asd a  
  TEXT2/sddasfkla dsajkh aksdjh fds asd asd-a
TEXT2/sddasfkla dsajkh aksdjh fds-asd asd a
TEXT2/sddasfkla dsajkh aksdjh fds-asd asd-a
dhasjkhdk askdjh ajks
dhasjkhd/k askdjh-ajks`

console.log(
  text.split('\n').filter(s => s.match(/^\s*TEXT[12]\/[^-]+-[^-]+\s*$/))
)
```

Comment: Ваш пример работает, но не с моим текстом )
Пробую разобраться, спасибо огромное!
Текст: "SIP/701-000293d1 macro-dial-one s 43 Up Dial SIP/700,,TtrI 701 3 171 SIP/700-000293d2 1516906884.571945"

Вместо SIP может быть IAX, Local - пока не суть важно, это я поставил в только_SIP

Comment: Используй `(SIP|IAX)`

Comment: пока дело не в этом, проблема в том что я не могу обозначить конец шаблона. А если в строке дальше встретится тире, данные вообще в шаблон не попадают.
Мне нужно, если в одной строке встретятся несколько таких шаблонов - они попали в массив. Строк так то несколько тоже )
В общем, надо чтобы по пробелу или табу после окончания text3 данный текст попадал в массив, и поиск шел дальше по строке.  

     var text = `SIP/text2-text3 
SIP/701-000293d1 macro-dial SIP/701-000293d2 
SIP/701-000293d3 macro`

попадает только первый и последний элемент, а два во второй строчке не попадают